# Product Flavor, Duplicate class, Error while merging dex archives

Tags: aspectj, dex, android-productflavors

I only get this error after I added the Gradle-AspectJ library (i.e. `apply plugin: 'com.archinamon.aspectj'` ).
Without flavors, in a new project there is no such issue, everything's just fine.
If you have encountered this problem and have the answer, please let me know. I have spent way too much time on this, tried everything I could think of and found.

Root level *build.gradle*:

```
buildscript { 
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    ext.detekt_version = "1.9.1"

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        ...
        classpath "com.archinamon:android-gradle-aspectj:4.2.1"
    }
}

...

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
...
        flatDir {
            dirs 'lib'
        }
    }
}
...
```

*app/build.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
...
apply plugin: 'com.archinamon.aspectj'
...

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
...
    }

    aspectj {
        includeAspectsFromJar "SecLib3.3.0"
        includeAllJars false
        ajcArgs << "-Xlint:ignore"
        excludeJar "mpulse", "aspectj"
        weaveInfo true
        compileTests = false
    }

    ...

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    flavorDimensions "server", "datasource"

    productFlavors {
        mock {
            // Mocked network layer
            dimension "datasource"
        }
        live {
            // Real network layer, different URLs based on "server" flavor dimension
            dimension "datasource"
        }

        fat {
            dimension "server"
            ...
        }
        ...
    }

    /* Removing unused flavor dimension combinations:
        - demo and prod mockDebug
     */
    variantFilter { variant ->
        if (variant.getFlavors().get(0).name != 'fat'
                && variant.getFlavors().get(1).name == 'mock') {
            variant.setIgnore(true)
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
...

    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    // Kotlin KTX
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0"

    // androidx
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta7"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"

    // Material Components
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-beta01"
...
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Type android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel is defined multiple times: /home/...../app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/fatMockDebug/out/android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel.dex, ...../app/build/intermediates/mixed_scope_dex_archive/fatMockDebug/out/android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel.dex","sources":[{"file":"...../app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/fatMockDebug/out/android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel.dex"}],"tool":"D8"}
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Type android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel is defined multiple times: ...../app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/fatMockDebug/out/android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel.dex, ...../app/build/intermediates/mixed_scope_dex_archive/fatMockDebug/out/android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel.dex
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:441)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:242)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:50)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:53)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.W.a(:87)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue.

The main source of the problem was *duplication* in dependencies (`firebase-core`, `firebase-crashlytics`, `firebase-perf`). Maybe aspectj has something to do with them?

After removing these three **Firebase** dependencies the problem seemed to go away.

Answer (score 0):

/app/build/intermediates/mixed_scope_dex_archive/fatMockDebug/out/android/support/v4/***app**/INotificationSideChannel.dex*

Just delete the folder(app) containing the file INotificationSideChannel.dex
The app folder is highlighted with bold letters in the above path
And run the project in the android studio. Now this error does not come.